# Displaying Complex Numbers as an Answer

Tags: javascript, html, complex-numbers

I appreciate any help.  I am writing this as a project I have in Pre-Cal.  I am tasked with writing a webpage, based in notepad that will run the quadratic equation with the user inputting the variables.  I have never written code before so while this is probably simplistic, it has taken me 3 weeks. The issue is correctly displaying complex number answers.  I tried linking to "math.js" at the top but it had no effect.  Here is what I am working with (I took off the explanations and bells and whistles) :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/mathjs@6.6.4/dist/math.js type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<label> Enter Variable "a"</label> <br>
<input type="text" id="a"> <br>
<label> Enter Variable "b"</label> <br>
<input type="text" id="b"> <br>
<label> Enter Variable "c"</label> <br>
<input type="text" id="c"> <br>
<input type="button" value="Solve" onclick="quad()"><br>
The Discriminant is:
<div id="dis"></div>
The 1st Root (also called zero) is:
<div id="res"></div>
The 2nd Root (also called zero) is:
<div id="res2"></div>
*Note that if the answers are not real numbers (a negative discriminant) the answer will read "NaN"*

<script>

function quad() {
var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
var b = document.getElementById("b").value;
var c = document.getElementById("c").value;
var Discriminant = (b*b-4*a*c);
var sroot = Math.sqrt(Discriminant);
var denominator =2*a;
var solution1 =(-b-sroot)/denominator;
var solution2 =(-b+sroot)/denominator;
document.getElementById("dis").innerHTML = Discriminant;
document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = solution1;
document.getElementById("res2").innerHTML = solution2;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to be able to show correct answers when Discriminant < 0? what would *you* consider "correctly displaying"? Also, you've loaded `math.js` ... but ... where is it you're using that library? you use `Math.sqrt` which is the native method, you should use `math.sqrt` - which is the `math.js` version

Comment: So if we had 3x^2-2x+5 the answers (per the textbook) would come out to be [1 - i * (square root) of 14 ]/3 and the same with 1+.....   Hopefully you understand that, not sure how to type in the format here.  As far as the math, just change it from www.......math.js to math.sqrt?  Will do.   Thank you.